# Authentication with Microsoft Azure AD in a multi-tenant app

Tags: django, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, python-social-auth

Following [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app), registered an application with **Accounts in any organizational directory**. The Tenant where the application resides is in "Default Directory" and has only one user, `tiagomartinsperes@gmail.com`. Also, the app has user assignment ([as pointed out here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist#cause-5-app-requires-user-assignment)) set to `No`

[image]

After, created another Tenant (different directory) and invited the external user `me@tiagoperes.eu`. That's the user I'm getting troubles logging into the previously created app.

Then, [enable the OAuth2 support](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azuread.html) using `social_core.backends.azuread.AzureADOAuth2` ([from here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/azuread.py)).

As I try to authenticate now, it works well with `tiagomartinsperes@gmail.com` but with `me@tiagoperes.eu` gives the following error

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application 'a9a22676-8a1c-4297-95d3-8cd89553220e' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

[image: Microsoft Auth Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the URL the user is redirected to. [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist?msclkid=ce865af7cc3f11ecb681eb3c54ebc1e1#solution-use-the-correct-sign-in-url), multi-tenant applications should redirect to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`.

As we see in the [Python Social Auth AzureADOAuth2 class](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/azuread.py#L43), the `BASE_URL` is

```
BASE_URL = "https://{authority_host}/{tenant_id}"
```

Since `authority_host = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"` and `tenant_id="common"`, we'd get the wrong url.

Changing that and signing in with the same user and now I get a request to add the permissions

[image]

[Reported that issue here too.](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/748)